# Apache event mpm configuration and apache worker mpm configuration

Tags: apache

**Apache event mpm configuration**
Hi can any one suggest me what should be the proper configuration of event mpm and worker mpm?

```
Presently i am using in both this below configuration.Please suggest me any change so that i can compare their performance.using this configuration the cpu usage of event mpm is very high and also performance is lower as compare to worker mpm?


    Startserver=16
    serverlimit=24
    maxclient=1536
    maxsparethreads=64 
    minsparethreads=64
    threadperchild=64
    threadlimit=64
```

Comment: Can any one help me with this ???